# SELECT data from hypertable

Tags: sql, postgresql

In partioned table I have 4 columns

```
itemid|clock     |value                |ns       
------|----------|---------------------|---------
 29823|1611360003|   1.4276002719238614|687885596
 23664|1611360024|   0.0846740050804403|691887511
 23252|1611360032|                  0.0|693202596
 23253|1611360033|  0.23664638269100743|693582940
```

Table has these partitions
[image]

How I can take hypertable table name using SELECT by clock?
Clock field stores data in unixtime but SELECT should be in datetime

All partitions can be extracted using this query

```
SELECT public.show_chunks('history');
```

> | show_chunks |
> | --- |
> | _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_2_chunk |
> | _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_5_chunk |
> | _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_7_chunk |
> | _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_9_chunk |
> | _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_11_chunk |

Comment: Is your table regular partitioned table?

Comment: Why would partitions matter?

Comment: Have you tried `select to_timestamp(clock) from history` ?

Comment: @MikeOrganek it shows 

to_timestamp       
-------------------
2021-01-22 02:00:03
2021-01-22 02:00:03
2021-01-22 02:00:03

But I need a hypertable name like as _hyper_1_9_chunk

Comment: @Hogan 
Because I wanna remove unuseful data based on data

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Yes it postgresql timescaledb extension

Comment: You are supposed to use timescale's functions to drop partitions  https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/data-retention